# The Different Propagators for the KG Field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, commutator, greens-functions, propagator, klein-gordon-equation

I am currently working through the first few chapters of Peskin and Schroeder and have arrived at the sections where the different propagators are discussed.

In regular Quantum Mechanics, the propagator is simply $\langle x|y\rangle$, therefore I was expecting an equivalent expression for the propagator of the Klein-Gordon field, namely $\langle0|\phi(x)\phi(y)|0\rangle$. Despite this being discussed first (on pg. 27), a few pages later (on pg. 29 and beyond), the retarded propagator and Feynman propagator are discussed. They are both derived from the expression $$\langle0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle.$$
Now I am wondering why this is such an interesting quantity and what the "actual" propagator is that gives the amplitude for a particle transitioning from position $y$ to position $x$. The difference between the Feynman and retarded propagators seems to only be the use of a different contour integration technique, so I am also wondering why this would even make a difference, if they are supposed to compute the same quantity. So my questions are as follows:

1. Which is the 'real' propagator giving the correct amplitude and why?
2. What is the function of the other propagators if they do not give the correct amplitude?
3. Why are propagators defined using a commutator?

Comment: On p. 14, P&S explain why the single particle propagator of reqular QM violates causality.

Comment: Yes, and also on pg. 27 it is shown that the regular propagator is nonzero outside the light cone. Also it is shown that the commutator vanishes outside the light cone. However, these arguments cannot be sufficient to explain why the propagator should be $\langle0|[\phi(x),\phi(y)]|0\rangle$. It only shows that if this is the propagator, it indeed vanishes where necessary and then an implication would be antiparticles travelling in the opposite direction.

Comment: On p.28 they motivate the commutator $[\phi(x),\phi(y)]$ because it is the "simplest thing we could try" to ensure that a *measurement* performed at one point cannot affect a measurement at another point when the points are spacelike separated. Does this answer your question 3 ?